# Extracting First Harmonic component from FFT block Output Array in SImulink

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink, simpowersystems

I have been working on a project to design a Phasor Measurement Unit(PMU) in Simulink. And one of the steps involves taking the first harmonic from the FFT block output array(The FFT block itself takes a phase signal as input). I am having trouble figuring out which element in the output array corresponds to the first Harmonic component.

I obtained a simulink file from the internet which uses the element u(2,1,1) from the FFT output array as the First Harmonic array.

[image: A screenshot of the block in question.]

If I am reading this correctly this denotes the the element in the 2nd row of the 1st column of the array(No idea what the Third 1 if for?).

My question to all this, how to understand that the element in u(2,1,1) denotes the first harmonic component?

Comment: The block is using standard indexing notation to get the element from the first 3 dimensions of a 3D array.  If your data is only a 2D array then you don't need the 3rd `1`.  The `FFT` block can generate N-D arrays, so whoever put the model together may have been using it to get a 3D array as output (of the FFT block) and hence needed the 3rd index.

Comment: And the element in the u(2,1,1) position alaways denotes the 1st harmonic component?

Comment: You'll need to read the doc for the FFT block to confirm how it orders its output.